# Separating hours from minutes in a given time value

Tags: java, android, time, jodatime

I'm currently working on a simple Time-Manager Application for Android Devices.
My Problem: I am getting a **time value** (that looks like this -> **6:51**) from a Server.
Now I want to separate the hours and minutes and I want the value to be **updated continuously**.

I have already looked into **joda-time** but cannot find anything myself that would solve my problem, if there is a solution in joda-time at all.

Should I try extracting the digits and build my time-format out of them or is there a better and simpler solution?
In case of you recommending me to extract the digits, how do I solve the problem with hours above 9.

Thanks for Help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joda Time minutes in a duration or interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214630/joda-time-minutes-in-a-duration-or-interval)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the time.

```
 String time="6:51"              //which is from server;
 String splitTime[]=time.split(":");
 String hours=splitTime[0];
 String minutes=splitTime[1];
```

Comment: Better preparing an array first and then fill it **once** by using split, in order to minimize the split operations.

Comment: Wroks perfectly fine and is pretty simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the string that you have is in the format `hh:mm`, then you can use `String.split` to separate them.

```
String arr [] = time.split(":");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting time from server as String `"6:51"` ?

[org.joda.time.LocalTime#parse(String)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#parse(java.lang.String)) will help you. LocalTime represent time without date. After parsing String you will be able to call methods `getHourOfDay,getMinuteOfHour`.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the value of time as String and use split to separate hours and minutes. Then, you can convert it to int again for future uses.

```
String Time = (String) time;
String Hour=time.split(":")[0];
String Minute=time.split(":")[1];
//If you want to use Hour and Minute for calculation purposes:
int hour=Integer.parseInt(Hour);
int minute=Integer.parseInt(Minute);
```

There should be no problem, if hours>9

Answer (score 0):

In [Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7651221/642706) 2.5.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "6:51" );
int hour = localTime.getHourOfDay();
int minute = localTime.getMinuteOfHour();
```